# AmCharts 4 - drill map - get country iso code

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I started a new project on AmCharts 4 maps. First I select a continent, then I choose a country.

How can I get iso_code clicked country?

Is it possible to hide other countries and show only selected on map?

My code:

```
  // Countries
  var countriesSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
  var countries = countriesSeries.mapPolygons;
  countriesSeries.visible = false; // start off as hidden
  countriesSeries.exclude = ["AQ"];
  countriesSeries.geodata = am4geodata_worldLow;
  countriesSeries.useGeodata = true;
  // Hide each country so we can fade them in
  countriesSeries.events.once("inited", function(){
    hideCountries(); 
  });

  var countryTemplate = countries.template;
  countryTemplate.applyOnClones = true;
  countryTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#a791b4");
  countryTemplate.fillOpacity = 0.3; 
  countryTemplate.strokeOpacity = 0.3;
  countryTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}";

  countryTemplate.events.on("hit", function(event){
    chart.zoomToMapObject(event.target);

// how can i get iso_code clicked country ?
// and hide other countries 

        showPoints(); // function show point on selected country
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the country code by using `event.target.dataItem.dataContext.id`.

```
countryTemplate.events.on("hit", function(event){
    chart.zoomToMapObject(event.target);
    var countryCode = event.target.dataItem.dataContext.id;
    // ...
});
```

To hide some countries you can use `countriesSeries.exclude` as you already did in your example code. Alternatively you can use `countriesSeries.include` which is obviously the opposite. ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mappolygonseries/#include_property)). The chart should recognize changes and rerender itself. But bare in mind, that changes on an array are not easy to detect, so you should reassign the `exclude` or `include` property. ([docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#Note_about_data_mutation))

> polygonSeries.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataArray));

Or you use the following syntax:

```js
countriesSeries.include.push("DE");
countriesSeries.include = [...countriesSeries.include];
```

Comment: Thanks! I starting understanding this. I use countriesSeries.include and set selected country but how can I send request refresh map from hit event ?

Comment: You have to reassign, so the chart recognizes the changes (https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/map/#Note_about_data_mutation). I updated my answer.